# How to configure CiviEvent for high volumes of repeating events (>800 events/month)?

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

We are a small museum now installing CiviCRM on Wordpress. We conduct walking tours for museum visitors: 4 tours/day, 7 days/week. We would like to offer on-line registration for the tours. I'm imagining a form that would let on-line visitors select the date and the time-of-day (10am, 12, 2, 4pm) and pre-pay the tour fee. This type of repeating event doesn't seem appropriate for CiviEvent's Repeating Event mode of operation because we would have upwards of 4x7x30=840 events per month and only a small portion would have any participants. Is there a work-around for what we want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to **use CiviEvent's built-in repeat-function** in order to achieve this.

Define one template per timeslot (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/event-templates) and batch-create the child-items (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/repeating-events/).

We handle 5000+ events/year like this without any problems.

Comment: We had something with similar numbers, 4 events a day every day for 4 months - no problem.

Comment: Thanks, Guitarman. I was afraid I was missing something. We can proceed as you suggested. I'm sorry for not checking the logic of the calculation I posted. Thanks, Birgit.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't answer your question but 4 tours per day 7 days a week doesn't get your 800 events a month - only approx 120 per months.  You don't have 30 weeks in a month but only 4 to 5 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to generating the events in CiviCRM itself would be to use the [CiviCRM Event Organiser](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser) plugin. This would enable you to sync Events provided by the [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) plugin with Events in CiviCRM. Using Event Organiser would give you a calendar and list of events in WordPress out of the box and, IMO, its UI for generating repeating event schedules is rather good.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I'll try CiviCRM Event Organizer.